# Style individual Acts_As_Taggable_on tags without having a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I am trying to loop through the tags in my list and show them as pill badges but without being linkable.

I'm currently doing this:

```
<%= raw @creator.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t), class: 'badge badge-pill badge-primary' }.join(' ') %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Gerard

Comment: Have you looked at [content_tag](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do not want the tags as a link then just use a `<span>` Instead of a link:

```
<% @creator.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary"><%= tag %></span>
<% end %>
```